# Zenmap: Can't get hostnames for clients just IP addresses

Tags: wireless, nmap, network-scanners

I have run both a quick and intense scan on my network with Zenmap and I can't get the hostnames of the clients. If I do an ARP scan I get some hostnames and if I use Fing app on my iPhone, I can see even more.

What can possibly cause that?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a security question. Seems like a basic networking question to me. DNS and DHCP are what you want to look for (nmap documentation: how does it resolve hostnames?).

Comment: The result can vary depending of a lot of factors... other client's configuration, firewalling, your nmap command, etc... hard to know

Comment: I would like to know what command did you use?

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing what command you have used for the scanning, it is not possible to tell you why they hostname didn't come up. While running a scan in Zenmap you can see the command it is executing.

Try running this command in Nmap or in Zenmap

nmap -sL 192.168.1.1/24

This command will give you the hostnames. The -sL flag tells nmap to do a simple DNS query for the specified range of ip. This allows you to find hostnames for all of the ip's without having sent a packet to the individual hosts themselves.

nmap -sn 192.168.1.1/24

You can use this command to scan every client in the range using the wildcard. This will give you the hostnames along with their IP addresses, and only pings the hosts to discover them.